# Partial order relation on the group of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, lattice-orders, ordered-groups

We know that the usual $\leq$ is a partial order relation on the group of integers $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z$ is a totally ordered with this partial order relation. Is there any other partially order relation  exist in $\mathbb Z$ which makes $\mathbb Z$ a partially ordered group (or totally ordered group)?

Comment: I think divisibility relation works.

Comment: @ Amir  Thank you.  $a, b\in \mathbb Z, a\leq b$ if and only if $a|b.$ I think this works for positive elements $\mathbb N$ only and  $\mathbb N$ will be a partially ordered set  where we do not have group structure.

Comment: Divisibility isn't compatible with addition $2 |2$ and $3|6$  but $2+3 = 5\mathrel{\not|} 8 = 2 + 6$.

Comment: I agree, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0$ and $1$ are related, then the only possible partial orders that make  $\mathbb Z$ into a partially ordered group are the usual order $\le$  and its reverse order $\ge$:

If $0 \prec 1$, then $1 = 0 + 1 \prec 1 + 1 = 2$, and so $n \prec n+1$ for all $n$ by induction.

If $0 \succ 1$, then $n \succ n+1$ for all $n$.

If $0$ and $1$ are unrelated, I don't know right now... I think you need to consider all integers that are related to $0$. Then there'll be  several linear orders "starting" at $0$ in both directions. For instance, if $0 \prec n$, then there will be arithmetic progressions of step $n$ starting at $k=0, \dots, n-1$.

Comment: @ Ihf thank you. I guess the usual order and reverse order are isomorphic. So we have only one order up to isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, they are mapped into each other by the negation automorphism in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @CAA, there is also the trivial, empty partial order, in which no pairs are related.

Comment: @Ihf, $0$ and $1$ are unrelated means if we take positive cone is just $0, 2,3,4,...$.

Comment: @CAA, no, if the smallest $n$ such that $0 \prec n$, then you'd get $0,n,2n,3n,\cdots$.

Comment: @Ihf will not it be isomorphic to usual order again by mapping $1 $ to $ n.$

Comment: @CAA, no, if for instance $0 \prec 2$ and $0\prec 3$ but $2$ and $3$ are unrelated. Any partial order that is not total cannot be isomorphic to the usual order.

Answer (score 3):

Take $P = \{x\in\mathbb Z: x = 0 \text{ or }x\geq 2 \}.$ Then $G = (\mathbb Z, P)$ is a partially ordered group with positive cone $P.$ In this case, the element $3\wedge4$ does not exist in $G.$ If $3\wedge 4 = 3,$ then $3\leq 4, 4 - 3\in P$ but $4 - 3 = 1\notin P.$ This implies $G$ is not orderisomorphic to usual order on the group $\mathbb Z.$